# call function when input type hidden value load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, popup

**Here the View Code:**

```
@Html.Hidden("projectId1", (String)("\"" + ViewBag.projectId1 + "\""))
```

i have another popup. when select a value from popup here load the value into `#projectId1`.there is no problem. but i have to run when `#projectId1` is data is get have to call controller.

I try

```
 $("#projectId1").load(function(){
      alert("");
 });
```

**Note:**
 I also try onchange,keyup,keypress

Comment: Try [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) instead

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery, you could [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) a custom event:

```
$("#projectId1").trigger("change");
```

And you can listen with:

```
$("#projectId1").on("change", function () {

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/byKak/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$("#projectId1").on('change',function(){
            alert("");
});
```

As the change event requires an actual browser event initiated by the user instead of via javascript code. You must trigger 'change' function manually.

```
$("#projectId1").val('1').trigger('change');
```

After updating the value you have to trigger change function manually like this:

```
$("#projectId1").trigger('change');
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3atjtr2/)

Comment: Its working on page load only when i update value cannot work

Comment: @SaravananArunagiri After updating value , You have to trigger change function manually by '$("#projectId1").trigger('change');'

Comment: see my inspect element value is 1 when page load. after i get from popup value is a2de332. but function is not working @Rohit

Comment: After your value is changed, have you triggered change event ? Can you show/paste your changed code in your question ??

Comment: get a answer. call a function from popup javascript. thank you